# Will OS Locale/ Language Culture affect casting?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, cultureinfo

I am trying to cast a numeric field (in db) to a decimal (in .net). I am using .Field extension method.

```
var data = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(val => new clsValues()
          {
              value1 = all.Field<decimal>("field1")
          }).ToList();
```

where clsValues is a class like this

```
class clsValues
{
    public decimal value1;
}
```

My doubt is my app is used both in the US & Germany. So, if the value being casted is 123.456 will it be changed to 123,456?

Comment: `numeric` and `decimal` don't have the notion of format. Local / language / culture / format only kicks in if you are converting to / from string (which your code as shown doesn't do).

Comment: It "may" happen, once got this problem with doubles. Check the dot / comma section at the windows language settings, or else take care of `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @Essigwurst Not in that code it can't. In _other_ code, sure.